# Посоветуйте сервер

Tags: java, android, сервер

Я новичок и хочу потренироваться с такой задачей.

У меня есть приложение, которое делает фото, и его нужно отправить на сервер. Насколько я понимаю нужно открывать URL соединение и с помощью post запроса. Что лучше для этого использовать?

Я сначала сделал отправку картинки на `Parse`, но у `Parse` это все работает без `URL` соединения, а нужно сделать на любом сервере для теста, но чтоб было `URL` соединение... Посоветуйте как это можно сделать? я так понимаю, что мне нужно в урл адресе указать адрес сервера? но как его найти?

И я слышал еще, что если это нужно только для того, чтоб потестить программу, то это можно сделать с помощью так называемой заглушки... А потом уже как дадут конкретный сервер, то вместо заглушки ставиться уже конкретные данные.

Помогите разобраться а то я совсем запутался... первый раз с этим...

Answer (score 2):

В качестве сервера можно использовать сервис на чем угодно, будь то JAVA, PHP, Perl или еще что... Вопрос в том, что должно произойти с этим изображением в дальнейшем? И отсюда уже плясать в выборе технологий на сервере.

Comment: Дополнил описание, а то я не совсем точно вначале описал, сорри

Answer (score 1):

Как понимаю, Вы хотите поднять HTTP API которое будет принимать файл и, например, записывать его на диск.

попробуй flask. 
это python-framework.
он достаточно простои и хорошо задокументирован

конкретно для твоей задачи:

1. [Uploading Files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/) - Quickstart загрузки файлов
2. [Flask-Uploads](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/) - "обвязка" для более сложной работы с файлами

> я так понимаю, что мне нужно в урл адресе указать адрес сервера? но как его найти?

по этому вопросу.

во-первых, тебе нужно рабозраться как можно достучаться до сервера. есть ли у него внешний IP-адрес, или же передача файлов будет только во внутренней сети и, соответственно, можно достучаться до сервера по локальному IP.

во-вторых, что бы разобраться откуда и куда у тебя есть доступ. Это можно проверить с помощью команды [telnet](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) или же [ping](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping)